# Problem using fl.controls in Flash Builder

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have a pure AS3 project created in Flash Builder and I am trying to use fl.controls.Slider. I decided to link the fl library as a SWC. I downloaded one from [here](http://apdevblog.com/update-using-flvideo-package-w-eclipse-and-fdt3/) and included it in the project Library path. And then I instantiate the slider this way (this is in the main Sprite):

```
var s:Slider = new Slider(); 
addChild(s);
```

No compile error, but when I launch the project, I get the following runtime error:

```
Main Thread (Suspended: TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null.)  
flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/addChildAt [no source]    
fl.controls::BaseButton/drawBackground  
fl.controls::BaseButton/draw    
fl.core::UIComponent/drawNow    
fl.controls::Slider/draw    
fl.core::UIComponent/callLaterDispatcher
```

Any idea what's going on? Is there a better way to use fl components in a pure AS3 Flash Builder environment?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really old, so I am just gonna copy-paste my answer from comment so I can accept it.

I found the answer, it's missing skins after all as mentioned here. So all I have to do is call setStyle on all the available skins of the component and define them, which I need to anyway since I am not going to use the default skin.

Answer (score 0):

That means that the variable s is null. This is because:

- You haven't imported the actual class
- The class doesn't exist in your swc

The first one is pretty obvious. To be sure the actual class exists in the swc you can open the swc with zip/rar program and look in the inclusion xml for the line:

```
<script name="fl/controls/Slider" mod="... etc
```

Edit:

Have you tried a different source for the swc? Or even compiled your own swc with the package by doing:

- Create a new FLA
- Drag and drop the components
- Export as swc

Comment: Yes, the class exists. I see "fl/controls/Slider" in the XML inside the SWC. Also, the class is definitely imported, otherwise, I'll get compile error. I have a feeling this is related to missing skins mentioned [here](http://de-co-de.blogspot.com/2008/03/wheres-my-skin.html)

Comment: I found the answer, it's missing skins after all as mentioned [here](http://de-co-de.blogspot.com/2008/03/wheres-my-skin.html). So all I have to do is call `setStyle` on all the available skins of the component and define them, which I need to anyway since I am not going to use the default skin.

Answer (score 0):

That means that the variable s is null. This is because:

You haven't imported the actual class
The class doesn't exist in your swc
The first one is pretty obvious. To be sure the actual class exists in the swc you can open the swc with zip/rar program and look in the inclusion xml for the line:

Have you tried a different source for the swc? Or even compiled your own swc with the package by doing:

Create a new FLA
Drag and drop the components
Export as swc